# How to construct logical expression for advanced slicing

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to figure out a cleaner way of doing the following:

```
import numpy

a = np.array([1,2,4,5,1,4,2,1])

cut = a == (1 or 2)
print cut

[ True False False False  True False False  True]
```

The above is of course a simplified example. The expression `(1 or 2)` can be large or complicated. As a start, I would like to generalize this thusly:

```
cutexp = (1 or 2)
cut = a == cutexp
```

Maybe, *cutexp* can be turned into a function or something but I'm not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Btw the second element in your result is wrong. It must be "True".

Comment: @JBernardo and you are absolutely right! The `(1 or 2)` expression did not have the effect I was hoping for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try [numpy.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html). Say

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,4,5,1,4,2,1])
>>> b = np.array([1,2]) # Your test array
>>> np.in1d(a,b)
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Ah, this will be very useful. However, I was hoping to write more general logic expression with and/or etc. I guess, I can mix your idea with e.g., `numpy.logical_and(b,c)` etc.-- thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> (a == 2) | (a == 1)
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Sorry, I muddled the question. I should have asked how to return a logical expression from a function. A pseudocode would be `a == get_cut_on_1_or_2` where `get_cut_on_1_or_2` is `1|2`

Comment: @covariantmonkey - No probs, hope it helped. Not sure I follow you though, do you mean: `a[(a == 2) | (a == 1)]`